# Why is my adding of my object to an NSMutableArray not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, grand-central-dispatch

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            NSError *error = nil;

            NSURL *urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"...", URL]];
            NSString *json = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlRequest
                                        encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                        error:&error];

            JKParseOptionFlags options = JKParseOptionStrict;
            NSDictionary *results = [json objectFromJSONStringWithParseOptions:options];

            NSString *body = [[results objectForKey:@"item"] objectForKey:@"description"];

            Article *article = [[Article alloc] initWithTitle:title URL:URL body:body];
            [self.articles insertObject:article atIndex:0];
        });
```

Right outside of that I have `[self.tableView reloadData];` but if I call `NSLog(@"%d", self.articles.count);` right after that it returns 0. Why is it not adding it? If I call an NSLog inside that block accessing article's body property it will print it, so the object seemingly gets created fine. And yes, the method that this is in does get called (by viewDidLoad).

Comment: When *I* do this it generally means I haven't actually allocated an NSMutableArray object for self.articles and all I have at the moment is a nil pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The body gets executed asynchronously, so it doesn't start running that body until some time after your function is done. So all you do is put some code on a queue (which will not be run until later), and check if the article got added to the list (which it won't, until later).

If you check inside the code, that is actually checking a while later, when the queue is done running the code...

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you more without seeing the declaration of your `articles` object but what this usually means is that the `NSMutableArray` object you're trying to use is nil.  At the same time that you're logging the article's body property, try logging the `articles` object as well.  If you declared your array as

```
NSMutableArray *articles;
```

Then it won't work - articles is still nil and can't accept objects. Declare/instantiate using one of the following options:

```
NSMutableArray *articles = [NSMutableArray array];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *articles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```